# AES GCM porting from python to C#

Tags: c#, .net, aes, aes-gcm

I am trying to port AES GCM implementation in python OpenTLS project, to C# (.Net). Below is the code in OpenTLS code:

```
#######################
### Galois Counter Mode
#######################

class AES_GCM:
    def __init__(self, keys, key_size, hash):
        key_size //= 8

        hash_size = hash.digest_size

        self.client_AES_key = keys[0 : key_size]
        self.server_AES_key = keys[key_size : 2*key_size]
        self.client_IV = keys[2*key_size : 2*key_size+4]
        self.server_IV = keys[2*key_size+4 : 2*key_size+8]

        self.H_client = bytes_to_int(AES.new(self.client_AES_key, AES.MODE_ECB).encrypt('\x00'*16))
        self.H_server = bytes_to_int(AES.new(self.server_AES_key, AES.MODE_ECB).encrypt('\x00'*16))

    def GF_mult(self, x, y):
        product = 0
        for i in range(127, -1, -1):
            product ^= x * ((y >> i) & 1)
            x = (x >> 1) ^ ((x & 1) * 0xE1000000000000000000000000000000)
        return product

    def H_mult(self, H, val):
        product = 0
        for i in range(16):
            product ^= self.GF_mult(H, (val & 0xFF) << (8 * i))
            val >>= 8
        return product

    def GHASH(self, H, A, C):
        C_len = len(C)
        A_padded = bytes_to_int(A + b'\x00' * (16 - len(A) % 16))
        if C_len % 16 != 0:
            C += b'\x00' * (16 - C_len % 16)

        tag = self.H_mult(H, A_padded)

        for i in range(0, len(C) // 16):
            tag ^= bytes_to_int(C[i*16:i*16+16])
            tag = self.H_mult(H, tag)

        tag ^= bytes_to_int(nb_to_n_bytes(8*len(A), 8) + nb_to_n_bytes(8*C_len, 8))
        tag = self.H_mult(H, tag)

        return tag


    def decrypt(self, ciphertext, seq_num, content_type, debug=False):
        iv = self.server_IV + ciphertext[0:8]

        counter = Counter.new(nbits=32, prefix=iv, initial_value=2, allow_wraparound=False)
        cipher = AES.new(self.server_AES_key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)
        plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[8:-16])

        # Computing the tag is actually pretty time consuming
        if debug:
            auth_data = nb_to_n_bytes(seq_num, 8) + nb_to_n_bytes(content_type, 1) + TLS_VERSION + nb_to_n_bytes(len(ciphertext)-8-16, 2)
            auth_tag = self.GHASH(self.H_server, auth_data, ciphertext[8:-16])
            auth_tag ^= bytes_to_int(AES.new(self.server_AES_key, AES.MODE_ECB).encrypt(iv + '\x00'*3 + '\x01'))
            auth_tag = nb_to_bytes(auth_tag)

            print('Auth tag (from server): ' + bytes_to_hex(ciphertext[-16:]))
            print('Auth tag (from client): ' + bytes_to_hex(auth_tag))

        return plaintext

    def encrypt(self, plaintext, seq_num, content_type):
        iv = self.client_IV + os.urandom(8)

        # Encrypts the plaintext
        plaintext_size = len(plaintext)
        counter = Counter.new(nbits=32, prefix=iv, initial_value=2, allow_wraparound=False)
        cipher = AES.new(self.client_AES_key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)
        ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)

        # Compute the Authentication Tag
        auth_data = nb_to_n_bytes(seq_num, 8) + nb_to_n_bytes(content_type, 1) + TLS_VERSION + nb_to_n_bytes(plaintext_size, 2)
        auth_tag = self.GHASH(self.H_client, auth_data, ciphertext)
        auth_tag ^= bytes_to_int(AES.new(self.client_AES_key, AES.MODE_ECB).encrypt(iv + b'\x00'*3 + b'\x01'))
        auth_tag = nb_to_bytes(auth_tag)

#       print('Auth key: ' + bytes_to_hex(nb_to_bytes(self.H)))
#       print('IV:         ' + bytes_to_hex(iv))
#       print('Key:        ' + bytes_to_hex(self.client_AES_key))
#       print('Plaintext:  ' + bytes_to_hex(plaintext))
#       print('Ciphertext: ' + bytes_to_hex(ciphertext))
#       print('Auth tag:   ' + bytes_to_hex(auth_tag))

        return iv[4:] + ciphertext + auth_tag
```

An attempt to translate this to C# code is below (sorry for the amateurish code, I am a newbie):

EDIT:

Created an array which got values from GetBytes, and printed the result:

```
byte[] incr = BitConverter.GetBytes((int) 2);
cf.printBuf(incr, (String) "Array:");
return;
```

Noticed that the result was "02 00 00 00". Hence I guess my machine is little endian

Made some changes to the code as rodrigogq mentioned. Below is the latest code. It is still not working:

Verified that GHASH, GF_mult and H_mult are giving same results. Below is the verification code:

```
Python:

key = "\xab\xcd\xab\xcd"
key = key * 10
h = "\x00\x00"
a = AES_GCM(key, 128, h)
H = 200
A = "\x02" * 95
C = "\x02" * 95
D = a.GHASH(H, A, C)
print(D)

C#:

BigInteger H = new BigInteger(200);
byte[] A = new byte[95];
byte[] C = new byte[95];

for (int i = 0; i < 95; i ++)
{
    A[i] = 2;
    C[i] = 2;
}

BigInteger a = e.GHASH(H, A, C);
Console.WriteLine(a);

Results:

For both: 129209628709014910494696220101529767594
```

EDIT: Now the outputs are agreeing between Python and C#. So essentially the porting is done :) However, these outputs still don't agree with Wireshark. Hence, the handshake is still failing. May be something wrong with the procedure or the contents. Below is the working code

EDIT: Finally managed to get the code working. Below is the code that resulted in a successful handshake

Working Code:

```
/*
 * Receiving seqNum as UInt64 and content_type as byte
 *
 */
public byte[] AES_Encrypt_GCM(byte[] client_write_key, byte[] client_write_iv, byte[] plaintext, UInt64 seqNum, byte content_type)
{
    int plaintext_size = plaintext.Length;

    List<byte> temp = new List<byte>();

    byte[] init_bytes = new byte[16];
    Array.Clear(init_bytes, 0, 16);

    byte[] encrypted = AES_Encrypt_ECB(init_bytes, client_write_key, 128);
    Array.Reverse(encrypted);
    BigInteger H_client = new BigInteger(encrypted);

    if (H_client < 0)
    {
        temp.Clear();
        temp.TrimExcess();

        temp.AddRange(H_client.ToByteArray());
        temp.Add(0);

        H_client = new BigInteger(temp.ToArray());
    }

    Random rnd = new Random();
    byte[] random = new byte[8];
    rnd.NextBytes(random);

    /*
     * incr is little endian, but it needs to be in big endian format
     *
     */
    byte[] incr = BitConverter.GetBytes((int) 2);
    Array.Reverse(incr);

    /*
     * Counter = First 4 bytes of IV + 8 Random bytes + 4 bytes of sequential value (starting at 2)
     *
     */

    temp.Clear();
    temp.TrimExcess();

    temp.AddRange(client_write_iv);
    temp.AddRange(random);

    byte[] iv = temp.ToArray();

    temp.AddRange(incr);

    byte[] counter = temp.ToArray();

    AES_CTR aesctr = new AES_CTR(counter);
    ICryptoTransform ctrenc = aesctr.CreateEncryptor(client_write_key, null);
    byte[] ctext =  ctrenc.TransformFinalBlock(plaintext, 0, plaintext_size);

    byte[] seq_num = BitConverter.GetBytes(seqNum);

    /*
     * Using UInt16 instead of short
     *
     */
    byte[] tls_version = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16) 771);

    Console.WriteLine("Plain Text size = {0}", plaintext_size);
    byte[] plaintext_size_array = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16) plaintext_size);
    /*
     * Size was returned as 10 00 instead of 00 10
     *
     */
    Array.Reverse(plaintext_size_array);
    temp.Clear();
    temp.TrimExcess();

    temp.AddRange(seq_num);
    temp.Add(content_type);
    temp.AddRange(tls_version);
    temp.AddRange(plaintext_size_array);

    byte[] auth_data = temp.ToArray();

    BigInteger auth_tag = GHASH(H_client, auth_data, ctext);

    Console.WriteLine("H = {0}", H_client);

    this.printBuf(plaintext, "plaintext = ");
    this.printBuf(auth_data, "A = ");
    this.printBuf(ctext, "C = ");
    this.printBuf(client_write_key, "client_AES_key = ");
    this.printBuf(iv.ToArray(), "iv = ");

    Console.WriteLine("Auth Tag just after GHASH: {0}", auth_tag);

    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes2 = new AesCryptoServiceProvider(); 

    aes2.Key = client_write_key; 
    aes2.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; 
    aes2.Padding = PaddingMode.None; 
    aes2.KeySize = 128;

    ICryptoTransform transform1 = aes2.CreateEncryptor();

    byte[] cval = {0, 0, 0, 1};

    temp.Clear();
    temp.TrimExcess();

    temp.AddRange(iv);
    temp.AddRange(cval);

    byte[] encrypted1 = AES_Encrypt_ECB(temp.ToArray(), client_write_key, 128);
    Array.Reverse(encrypted1);

    BigInteger nenc = new BigInteger(encrypted1);

    if (nenc < 0)
    {
        temp.Clear();
        temp.TrimExcess();

        temp.AddRange(nenc.ToByteArray());
        temp.Add(0);

        nenc = new BigInteger(temp.ToArray());
    }

    this.printBuf(nenc.ToByteArray(), "NENC = ");
    Console.WriteLine("NENC: {0}", nenc);

    auth_tag ^= nenc;

    byte[] auth_tag_array = auth_tag.ToByteArray();
    Array.Reverse(auth_tag_array);

    this.printBuf(auth_tag_array, "Final Auth Tag Byte Array: ");
    Console.WriteLine("Final Auth Tag: {0}", auth_tag);
    this.printBuf(random, "Random sent = ");

    temp.Clear();
    temp.TrimExcess();

    temp.AddRange(random);
    temp.AddRange(ctext);
    temp.AddRange(auth_tag_array);

    return temp.ToArray();
}

public void printBuf(byte[] data, String heading)
{
    int numBytes = 0;

    Console.Write(heading + "\"");
    if (data == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (byte element in data)
    {
        Console.Write("\\x{0}", element.ToString("X2"));
        numBytes = numBytes + 1;
        if (numBytes == 32)
        {
            Console.Write("\r\n");
            numBytes = 0;
        }
    }
    Console.Write("\"\r\n");
}

public BigInteger GF_mult(BigInteger x, BigInteger y)
{
    BigInteger product = new BigInteger(0);
    BigInteger e10 = BigInteger.Parse("00E1000000000000000000000000000000", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

    /*
     * Below operation y >> i fails if i is UInt32, so leaving it as int
     *
     */
    int i = 127;
    while (i != -1)
    {
        product = product ^ (x * ((y >> i) & 1));
        x = (x >> 1) ^ ((x & 1) * e10);
        i = i - 1;
    }

    return product;
}

public BigInteger H_mult(BigInteger H, BigInteger val)
{
    BigInteger product = new BigInteger(0);
    int i = 0;

    /*
     * Below operation (val & 0xFF) << (8 * i) fails if i is UInt32, so leaving it as int
     *
     */

    while (i < 16)
    {
        product = product ^ GF_mult(H, (val & 0xFF) << (8 * i));
        val = val >> 8;
        i = i + 1;  
    }
    return product;
}

public BigInteger GHASH(BigInteger H, byte[] A, byte[] C)
{
    int C_len = C.Length;
    List <byte> temp = new List<byte>();

    int plen = 16 - (A.Length % 16);
    byte[] zeroes = new byte[plen];
    Array.Clear(zeroes, 0, zeroes.Length);

    temp.AddRange(A);
    temp.AddRange(zeroes);
    temp.Reverse();

    BigInteger A_padded = new BigInteger(temp.ToArray());

    temp.Clear();
    temp.TrimExcess();

    byte[] C1;

    if ((C_len % 16) != 0)
    {
        plen = 16 - (C_len % 16);
        byte[] zeroes1 = new byte[plen];
        Array.Clear(zeroes, 0, zeroes.Length);

        temp.AddRange(C);
        temp.AddRange(zeroes1);
        C1 = temp.ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        C1 = new byte[C.Length];
        Array.Copy(C, 0, C1, 0, C.Length);
    }


    temp.Clear();
    temp.TrimExcess();

    BigInteger tag = new BigInteger();

    tag = H_mult(H, A_padded);
    this.printBuf(H.ToByteArray(), "H Byte Array:");

    for (int i = 0; i < (int) (C1.Length / 16); i ++)
    {
        byte[] toTake;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            toTake = C1.Take(16).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            toTake = C1.Skip(i * 16).Take(16).ToArray();
        }
        Array.Reverse(toTake);
        BigInteger tempNum = new BigInteger(toTake);
        tag ^= tempNum;
        tag = H_mult(H, tag);
    }


    byte[] A_arr = BitConverter.GetBytes((long) (8 * A.Length));
    /*
     * Want length to be "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 xy" format
     *
     */
    Array.Reverse(A_arr);

    byte[] C_arr = BitConverter.GetBytes((long) (8 * C_len));
    /*
     * Want length to be "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 xy" format
     *
     */
    Array.Reverse(C_arr);

    temp.AddRange(A_arr);
    temp.AddRange(C_arr);
    temp.Reverse();

    BigInteger array_int = new BigInteger(temp.ToArray());

    tag = tag ^ array_int;

    tag = H_mult(H, tag);

    return tag;
}
```

Using SSL decryption in wireshark (using private key), I found that:

The nonce calculated by the C# code is same as that in wireshark (fixed part is client_write_IV and variable part is 8 bytes random)

The value of AAD (auth_data above) (client_write_key, seqNum + ctype + tls_version + plaintext_size) is matching with wireshark value

Cipher text (ctext above) (the C in GHASH(H, A, C)), is also matching the wireshark calculated value

However, the auth_tag calculation (GHASH(H_client, auth_data, ctext)) is failing. It would be great if someone could guide me as to what could be wrong in GHASH function. I just did a basic comparison of results of GF_mult function in python and C#, but the results are not matching too

Comment: What do you mean by the output does not agree with Wireshark? The final result is the same for the function but are they being used differently?

Comment: You should NOT use ECB mode: https://image.slidesharecdn.com/poodle-151116184247-lva1-app6891/95/sslpoodle-history-repeats-itself-18-638.jpg?cb=1447699522

Comment: The methods `AES_CTR` and `AES_Encrypt_ECB` are not included in the code - could you past them here?

Comment: Instead of `Random` use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a final solution, but just an advice. I have seen you are using a lot the function `BitConverter.GetBytes`, `int` instead of `Int32` or `Int16`.

The remarks from the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method
>   depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or
>   big-endian.

As for when you are using the `BigInteger` structure, [it seems to be expecting always the little-endian order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207(v=vs.110).aspx):
value

> Type: System.Byte[]
>   An array of byte values in little-endian order.

Prefer using the `Int32` and `Int16` and pay attention to the order of the bytes before using it on these calculations.

Use log4net to log all the operations. Would be nice to put the same logs in the python program so that you could compare then at once, and check exactly where the calculations change.

Hope this give some tips on where to start.

Comment: Thanks rodrigogq. Agree with you. Will change the code accordingly and try it out

Comment: One major issue with GF_mult was that it was initializing e10 as BigInteger e10 = BigInteger.Parse("E1000000000000000000000000000000", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);. This was wrong. Somewhere found the correct way to be: BigInteger e10 = BigInteger.Parse("00E1000000000000000000000000000000", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);. My GF_mult is working fine now. I am getting same results for both python and C# in GF_mult

Comment: @frenzyman so it was the byte order really... as last modification, instead of just reversing the array, check before the format, like: `if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == true) Array.Reverse(var);`

Comment: great relief but not yet complete. I have somehow ensured that GF_mult, H_mult and GHASH functions are giving the same results in python and C# now. This is after a 100 rounds of checking line by line. However, I am still getting auth_tag as wrong. I have uploaded the working code till now, and also the verification script

Comment: I am now getting proper Auth Tag in both Python and C#. And it is the same. It has been verified manually. I have uploaded the code to the question. May be something is wrong with the procedure or the contents selected for creating the Auth Tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks rodrigogq. Finally got it working. BigInteger conversion at many places required array reversals. Updated the question with my amateurish code

Comment: Hey @frenzyman please if this answered helped you to achieve the solution, please mark it as the solution :) thanks!

Comment: Hi rodrigogq, Sorry for this, My humble request to you to please help me on the below query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699428/doing-ecdhe-key-exchange-using-c-sharp